# How do I make a background semitransparent in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

How do I make a semitransparent black background (of alpha, say 0.5) without using images in QT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I know is to start with this:

```
setStyleSheet("background:transparent;");
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

And then tweak until it works how you want it to from there, originally I found that tip over: [on the Qt forums](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/1107).

Comment: how do i adjust the alpha to say 0.5 though?

Comment: I think I might have found a simpler way but I've not had chance to try it, there's a [QGraphicsOpacityEffect](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsopacityeffect.html) that you can apply to your widgets, I've used the shadow one before and it allows fine alpha channel control.